# Comparison between datetimepicker and string

Tags: c#, class, datetime, comparison, datetimepicker

This is how I put the date in the variable

```
dateTimePicker8.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Form1.DBList[temp].Data); //DBList contains <Media> // Media is a class

List<Media> temp123 = new List<Media>(); //temp123 is just a temporary list
```

And this is how I try to do a query of dates but it doesn't work

```
foreach (var item in DBList)
{
    dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Data);

    if (dateTimePicker1.Value > dateTimePicker3.Value
          && dateTimePicker3.Value < dateTimePicker2.Value)
        temp123.Add(item);
}
```

I get this error:

> System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Do you think to post in which line you get that exception and the content of variables at that time.

Comment: the error is on the 
             dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Data); //item.data contains 12 Giu 2014

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tell it how to parse the date back out of that string:

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("12 Giu 2014", "dd MMM yyyy",
                                          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-CH"));
```

I specified the Italian culture since "Giu" is in Italian. Assuming your current culture is already Italian, you can replace that last parameter with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

---

Additionally, there's no need to create `DateTimePicker` controls just to store and manipulate dates. If you don't intend to display those pickers to the user, then just use `DateTime` variables.

Comment: This is how i edited the code but the if conditions doesn't work properly, temps123 contains wrong time interval, are the conditions wrong? I only want to add dates > datetimepicker1 and <datetimepicker2

            foreach (var item in DBList)
            {
                var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Data, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-CH"));
                //dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Data);
                if ((dateTimePicker1.Value < parsedDate) && (parsedDate > dateTimePicker2.Value))
temp123.Add(item);
                }

Comment: sorry for bad edit but it says i haven't enough reputation for a edited answer

Comment: The 2 timepickers are displayed to the user because he have to set the interval